How to change the casing of a string having no spaces
Recently, I have been looking for some library which can help me update the casing of a string which has no special characters.
For eg:
helloworld -> helloWorld (Lowercase to camelCase)
One method is the manual check with the schema I currently have. I want to know if I can do something else and my work is redundant.
Thanks in advance!!
Compared it with the existing schema which is already in camelCase and use it for transforming to lower/pascal/upper.

Your solution sounds fine.

The only way to automate this is using a dictionary. You'd still have to manually verify the results though...
